# HTML Expanding/Contracting Table - Up/Down Arrows

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm not new to HTML, but I am VERY new to JavaScripts (jQuery using JSFiddle) and CSS. So yeah, n00b. I'm having trouble understanding the coding!

I'm new here... I've tried to search if this question has been asked previously, but couldn't find anything. Apologies if I'm doubling-up. Hope not!

Anyway, I want to catalogue my entire movie collection on a HTML list, so I can open this list up on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. The problem tho, is that there's waaaay too much information to display on a small tablet screen, so I researched expanding "click-able" tables, and found this nifty tutorial:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Pn3m5/
```

The problem tho, is that I barely understand the coding behind the java. I'm getting there! Somethings make sense, but when I change it, save it and reload the HTML, it rarely works the way I want it to!

Plus having the default +/- script means that the entire row "wobbles" when you expand/contract the table because there's a size discrepancy between those two. So after some Googling, I found this site with a cool up/down arrow table:

```
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/
```

Shortly after reading this site, I decided to replace the generic unsightly +/- buttons for the up/down arrows. The trouble is that both HTML, JS and CSS codes are different from both tutorials, so I tried to "backwards engineer" them and merge them (with dismal results).

Here is the link for the arrows:

```
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/expandable-rows/arrows.png
```

*Further edit: The arrows provided in the link are black. I inverted the colors in Photoshop to see them as white with the black Background. Sorry for the inconvenience! I wish I could upload all my html, js, css and images all together with their respective subfolders to demonstrate properly!

The other images in this code have been edited by myself on Photoshop so aren't available online.
PROBLEM: I've managed to get it to look "OK", but when I click the down-arrow, they ALL change direction together, which is a royal pain. I only want to change the down-arrow specifically on the row I'm trying to expand upon, not all of them!

My heart tells me I have an error in my JavaScript file, maybe someone here reading this with a keen eye can spot my problem? I can't see it.

PLEASE HELP!

Here's my HTML code: (list.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Expandable List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
        </script>

<style type="text/css">
.myTable { background-color:#000000;border-collapse:collapse; }
.myTable th { background-color:#000000;color:white; }
.myTable tr td { background:#000000 url(img/back.png) repeat-x scroll center left; }
.myTable td, .myTable th { padding:0.5px;border:1px solid #666666; }
.myTable div.arrow { background:transparent url(img/arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px; width:16px; height:16px; display:block; }
.myTable div.up { background-position:0px 0px; }
</style>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black">

<font color="white">

<center><table class="myTable">
    <tr><td><div class="arrow"></div></td><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subtitles?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><center><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="img/tv.png"></a></center></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="10" valign="top"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><div class="arrow"></div></td><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subtitles?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><center><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="img/tv.png"></a></center></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td><div class="arrow"></div></td><td><p>Name</p></td><td><p>Year</p></td><td><p>Genre</p></td><td><p>Subtitles?</p></td><td><p>Length</p></td><td><p><center><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="img/tv.png"></a></center></p></td><td><p>Rating</p></td><td><p>Location</p></td><td><p>Res</p></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="10"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
    </td></tr>
</table></center>
</font>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript code: (scripts.js)

```
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=10]").find("p").hide();
    $("table").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ( $target.closest("td").attr("colspan") > 1 ) {
            $target.slideUp();
            $target.closest("arrow").prev().find("td:first").html("+");
        } else {
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
            if ($target.closest("arrow").find("td:first").html() == "+")
                $target.closest("up").find("td:first").html("-");
            else
                $target.closest("arrow").find("td:first").html("+");

                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");                
        }                    
    });
});
```

Here's my CSS code: (style.css)

```
table{ width: 90%; }
tr {border: 1px solid #666666;}

.scroll-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /*making the scroll have momentum on mobile devices
    http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements
    */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
/*hiding the scrollbar*/
.scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
 }
```

Please help! Any helpful suggestions for fixing these pesky up/down arrows would be greatly appreciated!

Gus.

"Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope!"

Comment: You may know HTML but you really need to work on them skills, still using `<font>` and `<center>`... not good.

Comment: Added an (imperfect) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/bj9k5ga8/).

Comment: Can you provide a url to the icons you are using ?

Comment: Obvious mistake: Some of your jquery class selectors are missing the `.` ( `arrow` instead of `.arrow`)

Comment: Here comes sort of a solution as [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/s3t5qdtb/). Currently you have to click on the `+`/`-` symbols in the first column (instead of anywhere into the cell) or the open text section to properly update the display. I cannot check the effects on the icon display since you haven't provided these. Changes in all of your files have been necessary.

Comment: Some words of advice: You will not be successful in web development unless you take the time to *thoroughly* learn the basics - take your time on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/), [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) and possibly some other sites (this includes the w3c standards and recommendations !).

Comment: Thank you, collapsar! I will have a look at those links you provided and will have a good read. I'm a pretty good learner and always looking for advice from pros. Please note that I edited my question above and provided a link for the arrow image as per your request. It's one image that gets shifted up or down 16 pixels upon clicking the <td> row. Your solution is a lot neater than mine, and I've so far updated my HTML, JS and CSS files, but I'm still having the same issues, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Ruddy. It's good hearing feedback from others; especially those that work in the industry. Would you be able to maybe point me in to the right direction, like how collapsar did, if you also know of any good sources to boost my limited knowledge?

Comment: I just edited the post again, @collapsar. I realized that my background is black and the icon in the link is black as well. Sorry for the mishap.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is incomplete, invalid, out-of-date, broad, riddled with errors and abandoned by the user almost two years ago with no answers.